# JQuery class selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an html text box with some having class names as **numbers**

```
<input type="text" name="msg_timeout" class="numbers" />
```

similarly there are different text box with class as **numbers**.I want to assign keydown event to those text box that has class as number so i tried with following ,but not working

```
$('input.numbers').each

$('.numbers').each

$('input.numbers:text').each

$('input:text.numbers').each

$('input[type=text]').each  // only this is working but it selects all textboxes.
```

kindly let me know idea.  **CODE BELOW**

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $('input.numbers').each(function() {

        $(this).get(0).oncontextmenu = function() { return false; };
           $(this).bind("keydown",function(event) {
           // alert(window.event);

            // Allow only backspace and delete
            if ( event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8  
                    && (event.keyCode >=96 && event.keyCode <=105) ) 
            {
                // let it happen, don't do anything
            }
            else {
                // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
                if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57 || event.shiftKey || event.ctrlKey || event.altKey ) {
                    event.preventDefault(); 
                }   
            }

            var forbiddenKeys = new Array('c', 'x', 'v');
            var keyCode = (event.keyCode) ? event.keyCode : event.which;
            var isCtrl;
            isCtrl = event.ctrlKey;
            if (isCtrl) {
                for (i = 0; i < forbiddenKeys.length; i++) {
                    if (forbiddenKeys[i] == String.fromCharCode(keyCode).toLowerCase()) {
                        //alert('You are prompted to type this twice for a reason!');
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        });
   });

});
```

Comment: All of your examples should work... so maybe something else is wrong in your code. Show some more than just the `.each`.

Comment: I agree with ThiefMaster. Are you calling these selectors after dom.ready like I've shown below?

Comment: I am calling the each within document.ready function

Comment: any ideas where i might be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you calling the selectors after dom.ready?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input.numbers').keydown(function() {
        // code here
    });
});
```

without the `$(document).ready()` it's unpredictable which elements will be present on the screen when your selector is evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to explicitly iterate over all matching elements to assign event handlers to them. The following will do the trick:

```
// bind a keydown handler to all input elements with class 'numbers'
$("input.numbers").keydown(function() {
    // handler implementation here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't posted your entire code, but I'm guessing you might also be adding some elements on the fly?

In that case.. use..

```
$("input.numbers").live('keydown', function() {
    // do stuff here
});
```

Comment: Also, as xzyfer suggested, ensure you're attaching stuff within `$().ready()`.

Answer (score 0):

you mean "numbers" not as text but as a number, a digit, integer?

```
$("input").filter(function() {
   return $(this).attr("class").match(/\d+/);
});
```